# Get selected TObject value from ComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, devexpress, vcl

How get TObject value from selected TcxComboBox eg.  For BMW => 2 or MERCEDES => 3

```
myTcxComboBox.Properties.Items.AddObject('AUDI',TObject(1));
myTcxComboBox.Properties.Items.AddObject('BMW',TObject(2));
myTcxComboBox.Properties.Items.AddObject('MERCEDES',TObject(3));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add an integer as an object, what you have to do is only casting that object to integer;

```
selected := NativeInt(myTcxComboBox.Properties.Items.Objects[myTcxComboBox.ItemIndex]);
```